# Reading Character in Java

Tags: java

I work in BlueJ in Windows. I tried to read a character in Java using the following method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InputStreamReader instream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(instream);
        char c = (char) stdin.read();
    }
}
```

When I compiled it, the compiler gave an error:

> Unreported exception `java.io.IOException;` must be caught or declared

I did not understand the problem. Can anyone suggest me a way to do it properly.

Comment: Do you know what [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) are?

Comment: Are you sure that `stdin.read()` should always work correctly? What do you think will happen if `System.in` will be closed for instance by some other thread? You will get `IOException` since we can't read from such stream, so you need to handle this exception by either catching it with `try-catch` or letting your method rethrow it.

Comment: Anyway you should not read single characters but entire Strings. Try using `readLine()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `stdin.read()` could throw an `IOException` which is what the error message is telling you.  You need to handle this by either declaring that your `main` method will throw it:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

or by handling the `IOException` inside `main` by using a `try`/`catch` like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        InputStreamReader instream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(instream);
        char c = (char) stdin.read();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle error in some way
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krock. I am using throw IOException. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try{
        InputStreamReader instream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(instream);
        char c = (char) stdin.read();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        // write your handling
    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

// You can catch relevant multiple exceptions using catch block. If you are not sure of specific exception, catch generic **Exception**. All sub classes of Exception should be handled first and generic **Exception** should be caught in the last.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block to handle IOException in your code. you can do this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {

            InputStreamReader instream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(instream);
            char c = (char) stdin.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```